# XDT Transformation in the Target Web config file

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, web-config, web-config-transform, xdt-transform

After applying transformation rules on the below target config file and target config file has the output printed in one line continuously but not one line after another. Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Below is my source config file:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">  
        <system.serviceModel xdt:Transform="Replace">
           <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"></serviceHostingEnvironment>
            <client>
              <endpoint address="test" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="test" contract="test" />
              <endpoint address="test" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="test" contract="test" name="test" />
              <endpoint binding="test" bindingConfiguration="test" contract="Mango" name="test" />
    </system.serviceModel>
        </client>
</configuration>
```

My Target web.config looks like:

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel><serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"></serviceHostingEnvironment><client><endpoint address="test" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="test" contract="test" /><endpoint address="test" binding="basicHttpBinding"bindingConfiguration="test" contract="test" name="test" /><endpoint binding="test" bindingConfiguration="test" contract="Mango"name="test" /></system.serviceModel> </client></configuration>
```

Comment: I tried many times but failed to reproduce your scenario. Above transform config file is in malformat. Tag </client> should be inside tag <system.serviceModel>. Is it a typo or it is exactly what it is in the transform config file? With above malformated config file, i cannot even build my pipeline successfully.  And what tasks does you use to apply the transformation in your pipeline?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @LeviLu-MSFT. Yes, it was a typo and yes </client> this tag should preset inside servicemodel. Now you try this config by putting </client> tag inside then u get output printed in one line continuously which is not supposed to be.

Comment: I tried with </client> tag inside. Still cannot reproduce this case. My web.config is in the right structure after being transformed. What task are you using to apply the transform. Can you share your original web.config(before transformed)

Comment: Tasks were the first step is to transform my source config to change app settings and some other settings, once done next step is to deploy web and app on target servers using transformed config. Here everything is working as expected in transform config the only thing I' concern about is after applied transform config , my target config getting print some of its app settings in one line continuously.

Comment: <configuration>  
        <system.serviceModel>
           <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"></serviceHostingEnvironment>
            <client>
              <endpoint address="test" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="test" contract="test" />
              <endpoint address="test" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="test" contract="test" name="test" />
              <endpoint binding="test" bindingConfiguration="test" contract="Apple" name="test" />
     </client>
          </system.serviceModel>
       
</configuration>